# how to create a 5 by 5 matrix in c# windows form

Tags: c#, matrix

```
 for (int i = 0; i!=5; i++)
 {
    for (int j=0; j!=5; j++)
    {
        array times[i, j] = int.Parse(Tb_First.Text);
        list_Matrix.Items.Add(array times[i,j]);
    }
 }
```

or

```
 int[,] numbers = new int[,]  {{ 1 , 2 , 3, 4, 5 }, { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }} ;

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i !=5; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j !=5; j++)
         {
             list_Matrix.Items.Add(numbers[i,j].To String());                  
         }
     }
 }
```

i have tried this but it isn't working.. is there any other methods to generate a 5 by 5 matrix in C# in windows form. the input is written on text box and the matrix should be in a list box. some one please help me

Comment: What do you mean "isn't working"? You don't even create a 5x5 array in your example (it's a 2x5 array). Which Exception do you get?

Comment: yeaa.. i din notice tat :(..

Answer (score 2):

try it

```
var numbers = new int[5,5] { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 
{ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }};

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            list_Matrix.Items.Add(numbers[i,j].To String());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u so much. it worked :)..how do we list the matrix in a listbox from a textbox? i tried this code. bt it isnt working                                         
       
          

           
            for (int i = 0; i!=2; i++)
                for (int j=0;j!= 2;j++)
                {
                  lst_Matrix.Items.Add(arraytimes[i,j].ToString(tb_First.text));
                }

Comment: well come. accept my answer, I mean click right. ur next question is not clear to me. U may come to my face book https://www.facebook.com/atish.iit

Answer (score 2):

There is a source by microsoft for it

[Programming guide (Multidimensional - Arrays /Matrix)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays)

> var numbers = new int[5,5] { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },  { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, {
>   1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }};

I guess discribe the int[,] is better than "var" to show that secound sample is almost correct. The problem is just the incorrect size.